# Is it possible to save data from local storage to the databse mssql

Tags: javascript, php, local-storage

I had collected data from difefrent pages and stored in the local storage. I want to save it to the database MySQL

**my javascript code :**

```
<script>
   $('#inscrit').click(function(){
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var ip_offre = localStorage.getItem('offre_ip');
    var offre= localStorage.getItem('offre');
    var pays = localStorage.getItem('pays');
    var nombre = localStorage.getItem('nbr_sms');
    var tot = localStorage.getItem('totale');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "get_data_front.php",
        data: {email: email,ip_offre: ip_offre, offre: offre, pays: pays, nombre: nombre, tot: tot},

        success: function (data) {


       },
        error: function (xhr) { // if error occured
          alert("Error occured.please try again" + xhr);
        }
      });




        });
 </script>
```

**My php code "get_data_front.php"**

```
<?php

include_once "config.inc.php";
global $sqlserver; 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$email=$_POST['email']; 
$ip_plan=$_POST['ip_offre'];
$plan=$_POST['offre']; 
$pays=$_POST['pays']; 
$nbr=$_POST['nombre'];  
$totale=$_POST['tot']; 


$sqlinsert = $sqlserver->prepare("insert into t_data_from_front 
                            (S_EMAIL,I_NB_SMS,S_PAYS,S_PRICE,S_PLAN,S_IP_PLAN,B_TRAITE)
                    VALUES($email,$nbr,$pays,$totale,$plan,$ip_plan,)");     
$resultinsert= $sqlinsert->execute() or die(var_dump($sqlinsert->errorInfo()));

?>
```

The insertion in the database is done but I get all fields NULL .
Thank you guys.

Comment: 1) Count the Columns and then count the values in the VALUE clause. You missed a value. This must be generating an error. Are you sure the insert is working. I doubt it!

Comment: 2) What do you see from your error display?

Comment: @RiggsFolly data validation failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query:

```
"insert into t_data_from_front(S_EMAIL,I_NB_SMS,S_PAYS,S_PRICE,S_PLAN,S_IP_PLAN,B_TRAITE)VALUES($email,$nbr,$pays,$totale,$plan,$ip_plan,)"
```

is missing a parameter, your specifing, 7 columns:

```
S_EMAIL,I_NB_SMS,S_PAYS,S_PRICE,S_PLAN,S_IP_PLAN,B_TRAITE
```

and only passing 6:

```
$email,$nbr,$pays,$totale,$plan,$ip_plan,
```

Comment: yes but all i get is Undefined index  $email=$_POST['email']; 
     $ip_plan=$_POST['ip_offre']; .....

Answer (score 1):

You should change your json to:

```
{'email': email,'ip_offre': ip_offre, 'offre': offre, 'pays': pays, 'nombre': nombre, 'tot': tot}
```

What you were doing is that parameter name was not email but it was the value of the object email.
So if:

```
var email = 'test@test.com'
```

The json you were sending was actually:

```
{'test@test.com': email,'ip_offre': ip_offre, 'offre': offre, 'pays': pays, 'nombre': nombre, 'tot': tot}
```

Comment: All i get is Undefined index of  $email=$_POST['email']; ... and when i use var_dump($email)  NULL

Comment: That means you are not sending the email value in the post.